# std::wstring: concatenation with + has no effect

Tags: c++, string, boost, stl

The solution is probably obvious, but I do not see it. I have this simple C++ code:

```
// Build the search pattern
// sPath is passed in as a parameter into this function
trim_right_if(sPath, is_any_of(L"\\"));
wstring sSearchPattern = sPath + L"\\*.*";
```

My problem is that the + operator has no effect (checked in debugger). The string `sSearchPattern` is initialized to the value of `sPath` only.

Notes: `sPath` is a `wstring`.

Example of what I want to achieve:

`sSearchPattern -> C:\SomePath\*.*`

**More Info:**

When I look at sPath in the debugger, I see two NULL characters after the last character. When I look at sSearchPattern, the "\*.*" is appended, but after the two NULL characters. Any explanation for that?

Comment: What is the declaration of `sPath`?

Comment: How do you determine that it has no effect? What do you do with `sSearchPattern`?

Comment: Post real code please. Your problem is almost guaranteed to be elsewhere.

Comment: Are you really assigning `char*` to `wstring`?

Comment: Added declaration of sPath. I checked the content of sSearchPattern in the debugger. And this is real code.

Comment: @HelgeKlein: I can't see any declaration of `sPath`, though  :-(

Comment: @KerrekSB: sPath is a function parameter.

Comment: Please don't change your question back and forth, but instead update it by adding additional info.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I just put it in. If this isn't the right thing, he will have to fix it. Otherwise we would have to close this question as not answerable.

Comment: @HelgeKlein: Hell, then just write the code that's necessary to reproduce the issue! Look at my example code. This works. What's different in yours?

Comment: @HelgeKlein I added a second `\` to `C:\SomePath\\`. In your code there are two `\\` after `C:`, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I found out the two NULL characters stored at the end of the string were the problem. Apparently std::wstring does not care about NULLs like good old C string does. If it thinks a string is 10 characters long, it does not care if some of those 10 characters are NULL characters. If you then append to that string, the additional characters get appended after the 10ths char. If the last characters of the string happen to be NULLs, you get:

> `C:\\SomePath\0\0\\*.*`

Such a string cannot really be used anywhere.

How did I get the NULL characters at the end of the original string? I used wstring.resize() in some other function which pads the string with NULLs. I did this in order to pass &string[0] to a Windows API function expecting a LPWSTR.

Now that I know this does not work I use a true LPWSTR instead. That is a bit more clumsy, but it works. Coming from MFC, I thought I could use std::wstring like CString with its GetBuffer and Release methods.

Comment: Use c_str() when you need LPCWSTR. No need for anything clumsy.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I'm pretty sure he's not talking about read-only access.

Comment: @BenVoigt, then he should use a `std::vector<WCHAR>`

Comment: @bdonlan : In C++11 anyway, there is no compelling reason to use `std::vector<char>` over `std::string` for read-write access.

Answer (score 11):

This should work, and indeed works for me on VS2010, SP1:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    const std::wstring sPath = L"C:\\SomePath";
    const std::wstring sSearchPattern = sPath + L"\\*.*";

    std::wcout << sSearchPattern << L'\n';

    return 0;
}
```

This prints

`C:\SomePath\*.*`

for me.

Comment: For those that don't trust :-) http://ideone.com/FVBRN and http://ideone.com/zmHJw (two different versions of gcc)

Comment: @Ben Voigt: This is a `std::wstring + pointer`, and is not an error.

Comment: Your code is correct, but my problem was somewhere else (see my answer).

Comment: @thanatos grace period edit made ben's comment look odd. Original version of answer was different.

Comment: @David Heffernan: I was wondering if it was that... I kindof hate when that feature does that. It's like someone is rewriting history...

Comment: @Thanatos: Rewriting history seems to be popular on SO, Jeff does it all the time on meta. `:)` Seriously, though, the original answer indeed contained an error. I removed it when that part of the answer became obsolete altogether after Helge changed his question, Ben added his comment while I was doing this (or shortly afterwards, no doubt still looking at the old answer). I didn't mean to make Ben's statement seem dumb. I only realized that this change wasn't recorded now that I saw the ongoing comment discussion about it.

Answer (score 1):

Something in your real code is adding extra null characters to the end of the string. Your bug lies in that code.

String concatenation works perfectly well. `std::wstring` is not null terminated and so concatenation just adds on to the end of the buffer. This makes `std::wstring` somewhat different from a C string because it can hold null characters. I suspect this nuance is the source of all the confusion.

Comment: trim_right_if is a boost function and it is not the cause of my problem (see my answer).

Comment: Well, you told us that sPath did not have nulls so what else could I reasonably conclude?

Comment: None of us could have known this, you did not provide the necessary information. Of course it's hard to know what information is necessary if you don't know what's causing the bug, but this is why it is important to boil faulty code down to a complete, self-contained, and preferably compilable repro-case. Had you done so, you would very likely have found the problem yourself before posting here. But even if not, you would have had the perfect sample to post here, very likely having you question answered within 5mins. Bottom line: There's no shortcut to boiling down a bug to a repro-case.

Comment: @helge Why did you leave an ungrateful comment and post an answer repeating what I said, namely the different handling of nulls?